# Debian startup script doesn't start

Tags: debian, scripting, startup, services

I'm trying to make a specific script load on start on Debian.
I have tried to put the script on /etc/rc.local but no success.
Now I have made a service script that runs my specific script. The code of the service script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          script
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Default-Start:     5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start script at boot time
# Description:       Enable service .
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting script"
    /usr/local/bin/script1
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping script"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/script {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Now I can test if my script is run as a service using `sudo service <script> start`

My code of `/usr/local/bin/script1` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 5> >(logger -t $0)
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
PS4='$LINENO: '
set -x

FILE=/share/_ngrok
NAO_ESTA_ESCRITO=0

touch $FILE
/usr/local/bin/ngrok tcp 22 --region eu > /dev/null &
sleep 5
URL=`/usr/local/bin/ngrok_url`
grep -q -F "$URL" $FILE || NAO_ESTA_ESCRITO=1
if [ $NAO_ESTA_ESCRITO -eq 1 ]; then
  /usr/local/bin/ngrok_url > $FILE
  /usr/bin/drive push -no-prompt -quiet $FILE
fi
exit 0
```

When I run `/usr/local/bin/script1` from bash it runs successfully but when I run `sudo service servicescript start` it doesn't run successfully. But when I do `sudo service servicescript otherarg` it runs successfully, so the service script is well configured. It is just the `start` that doesn't work on the service.
When I do `sudo service servicescript start` I get this error:

> Job for script.service failed. See 'systemctl status script.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

When I do `systemsctl status script.service` I get this message:

> ● script.service - Info
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/script.service; enabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Qui 2017-03-23 17:19:25 WET; 2min 35s ago
>     Process: 7710 ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/killscript (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>     **Process: 11689 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/script1 (code=exited, status=2)**
>    Main PID: 11689 (code=exited, status=2)

Comment: If you run `systemsctl status script.service` as root after the failed start attempt, it prints the logged error messages as well. They should help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're mixing all three init systems:

- sysVinit `/etc/init.d/daemon start/stop/restart`
- upstart `service daemon start`
- systemd `systemsctl status script.service`

Find out what your `init` system is

```
 stat /proc/1/exe
```

> File: '/proc/1/exe' -> '/lib/systemd/systemd'

So it's systemd which is the latest and new standard.

Here is a link for a howto:
[How to automatically execute shell script at startup boot on systemd Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux)

Remember that noninteractive shells don't have the env set such as `PATH`, you either need to set the PATH or give the full path for each command such as `/bin/sleep`.

When using `systemd` you might want to use `journald` instead of log files. In that case you'd replace `logger` with `systemd-cat`.

Comment: The `service` command is designed to do the right thing under all possible init systems, so it's a valid alternative at all times.